# How to create good mesh topology for a complex shape

Tags: mesh, topology

I have been searching for an answer to no end, but maybe I am wording it incorrectly. I have this dieline that I need to bring into Blender and create a mesh. See attached. How can I create a clean topology for this mesh? There are a lot of circles and I am not sure how to connect all the lines. I need to emboss some circles at different heights, while others will be "see through" and some will be translucent. I already created a pretty ugly one, I just don't know how to do this properly. Also attaching. Any guidance appreciated. [image]

[image]

Comment: Hello what do you mean by "I need to emboss some circles at different heights, while others will be "see through" and some will be translucent", is the object supposed to be flat with a bit of thickness? You don't neessarily need all these edges, ngons are ok if they are coplanar with their adjacent faces. So maybe tell a bit more and share your file?

Comment: Maybe show an image of the original object if you have one?

Comment: Please also tell us what the mesh is for. Printing, or visualization?

Comment: Hello @moonboots. Here are images of what I am trying to make. It is is just for visualization. The thickness of this membrane switch is .7 mm in real life. https://imgur.com/a/7CfpRMB. Do you see in the images where the circles have special embossing or dome effects? Also, where the red oval is translucent. I couldn't @ robin.

Comment: Shouldn't the buttons be separate objects?

Comment: One the membrane switch itself it is all together, so I copied that. Do you think it would be better if I made the buttons separate objects? I guess that would eliminate this whole topology confusion I am going through.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to at you. @moonboots

Comment: It looks like they are not part of the same object IRL so as a 3d object you could do separate objects or only one object but with separate meshes

Comment: Yeah, in real life it only looks like different objects because it was embossed and they change the texture on the circles. My company manufactures it. I totally forgot you can have separate meshes in one object, that seems like the way to go. Thanks so much @moonboots.

Comment: So I couldn't figure out how to have these as separate objects and still create the type of texturing I needed to with them all being one piece? Anywho, I used an addon to re-topo it and it works great now. https://imgur.com/a/yxupoHX. Just thought I would share in case anyone runs into something similar. I used "Quad Remesh"